# Jetty websocket client issue

Tags: websocket, jetty

Use Eclipse IDE in an attempt to create a java websocket client for an OpenHab project, thus using default Jetty websocket library. The OpenHab project intend to connect to a websocket endpoint requiring token authorization, send a request message and retrieve live/continuous measurements.

So, I have

```
public static final String SUBSCRIPTION_URL = "wss://api.tibber.com/v1-beta/gql/subscriptions";
```

Further, my WS open code:

```
public void open() throws Exception {
    if (isConnected()) {
        logger.warn("Open: connection is already open");
    }
    logger.warn("Connecting to: {}", SUBSCRIPTION_URL);

    sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory(true);
    sslContextFactory.setTrustAll(true);

    client = new WebSocketClient(sslContextFactory);
    client.setMaxIdleTimeout(360 * 1000);

    TibberWebSocketListener socket = new TibberWebSocketListener();

    request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
    String token = new StringBuilder("Bearer ").append(configuration.getToken()).toString();
    request.setHeader("Authorization", token);
    request.setSubProtocols("graphql-subscriptions");

    client.start();
    client.connect(socket, new URI(SUBSCRIPTION_URL), request);

}
```

However, with this code it seems like I get connected, but end up with an IOException: Broken pipe after 1 minute. I get the same error both if I just connect without message / connect with send message.

```
   13:59:15.987 [safeCall-1] WARN  o.o.b.t.i.handler.TibberHandler:346 - Connecting to: wss://api.tibber.com/v1-beta/gql/subscriptions
13:59:16.390 [@1379116703-141] WARN  o.o.b.t.i.handler.TibberHandler:385 - Connected to Server
14:00:16.430 [@1379116703-142] WARN  o.o.b.t.i.handler.TibberHandler:392 - Closing a WebSocket due to Disconnected
14:00:16.434 [@1379116703-139] WARN  o.o.b.t.i.handler.TibberHandler:399 - Error during websocket communication: Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.flush(SslConnection.java:928)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.flush(FrameFlusher.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.process(FrameFlusher.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.outgoingFrame(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.io.WebSocketClientConnection.outgoingFrame(WebSocketClientConnection.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.close(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillable(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillable(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:782)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
14:00:16.435 [@1379116703-139] WARN  o.o.b.t.i.handler.TibberHandler:392 - Closing a WebSocket due to Broken pipe
```

Answer (score 0):

> java.io.IOException: Broken pipe

That means the OS or network below Java (and Jetty) detected that the connection was closed.

"Broken Pipe" is actually fairly common, especially with mobile devices or wireless networking.

Not much Java or Jetty can do about it either, it happened outside of its control.